# Bandits from quests appearing on fast travel or building exit

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just started a new character on 11th April 2012. After completing the kill-a-dragon-at-western-tower quest, and buying Breezehome, I now appear to have a greeting committee of bandits after fast travel.

First, upon leaving Breezehome, the bandits from Embershard Mine appeared and were helpfully cut down by guards and citizens. This was the first go-kill-guys-over-there quest I picked up in the game, the bounty from Falkreath, and the quest was completed as soon as all the bandits died in Whiterun. I fast travelled to Falkreath to hand in the bounty to Nenya (2 transitions - Whiterun to Falkreath, Falkreath to Jarl's house). I then fast travelled to Riverwood, then to Whiterun (total 4 transitions), when the bandits from Valtheim Keep spawned and were killed by guards (Companions quest; incidentally the second go-kill-them-over-there quest I picked up).

This may be a patch 1.5.26 bug, related to the issue described here: [Why did enemies spawn around me when I fast traveled after the latest patch?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52797/why-did-enemies-spawn-around-me-when-i-fast-traveled-after-the-latest-patch)

I'm using Windows 7, Skyrim 1.5.26, SkyUI, and a couple of other mods (alchemy storage, weapon crafting, better horses).

Is anyone else getting this or similar behaviour?

Added Observations: It seems that going into Breezehome for the first time after getting the quest to kill the bandits from Halted Stream Camp from The Bannered Mare spawns the bandits in the house. After some testing, it appears that fast travelling to Riverwood will cause the quest marker to appear in Whiterun, and the bandits to spawn there after fast travelling to Whiterun. I also notice that the spawn point seems to be the doorway of Breezehome. What in Tamriel is going on?

Comment: Clearly the bandits have gotten more aggressive, and are no longer content to sit in their isolated forts.  Its time for some raiding!

Comment: Seems that way - that, or they just really really like my house.

Comment: @ysabet Have you used any Conjuration - Reanimate spells previously on those bandits?

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue, basically any enemies I run past and don't kill end up appearing the next time I quick travel  (my simple solution was to kill everything I come across).  It's funny though, I also picked up a horse somewhere. For a while he'd reappear after a quick travel and then start trotting back to whereever he came from. I mounted him and rode away, then he'd flash away from me as I got off. He was with me until I went up to see the Greybeards. I dismounted to kill a sabertooth and he rubberbanded off the edge.  Later I found his corpse in the river below :'( RIP Burt.

Comment: It seems a complete delete and reinstall has fixed the problem for new characters. I still need to test with old characters to see if I can revive them.

Comment: @galacticninja nope, my character(s) didn't even know any.

Answer (score 2):

If you have stollen enough, while you might not have a reputation in particular holds, you can still have a hit put on you that will be carried out by thugs, or someone hiring bandits to get what you have.

Answer (score -1):

It's part of the game's AI. Everytime you fast travel. The time is fast forwarded and most of the NPCs and enemies(such as crabs,wolves and other animals) are respawned. Sometimes the bandits too are treated this way and they end up appearing in the wrong place when you fast travel. There is nothing much to worry about. You should only be concerned when you are cornered by 10 dragons after you've fast travelled xD

Comment: No bandit should EVER spawn in your own house, fast travel or not. That is a bug, not an intended feature.

Comment: Obviously its a bug. Sometimes its hard to fix a bug when you consider such a massive environment like Skyrim. Let's hope they're fixed in the upcoming patches.

Comment: I woulkd assume it fixed by now, this post is from around patch 1.5, the latest patch is 1.9